# Seeking explainers on C++11 printf format args that consume more than one value

Tags: c++, c++11, printf

I have started working in a code base heavily using C++11. I am finding many resources to help me learn, but I can't find any mention of a type of printf format string I am seeing used:

```
printf( "%.*s", integerValue, charPointer );
```

I think I know what it is doing: the integerValue is the length of the character buffer. However, my decades of C/C++ tells me that is a single argument specification in the format string, yet it consumes two values after the format string.

Where is this newfangled behavior documented? Are there more multiple-value consuming printf format args like this? I've been searching printf format string documentations, and finding nothing.

Comment: "Where is this newfangled behavior documented?" In the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) of course, as always. You should always look through them first :)

Comment: And by "newfangled" you mean "old as the hills," right? :)

Comment: I swear I looked at man pages first, as well as the page linked by the answer below. I must have looked right over the info I wanted and not realized it. My use of "newfangled" was humor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is a good reference for the format specifiers. In some detail, then, the conversion specification consists of:

> - introductory `%` character
> - (optional) one or more flags that modify the behavior of the conversion:
>
>   - `-`: the result of the conversion is left-justified within the field (by default it is right-justified)
>   - `+`: the sign of signed conversions is always prepended to the result of the conversion (by default the result is preceded by minus only when it is negative)
>   - *space*: if the result of a signed conversion does not start with a sign character, or is empty, space is prepended to the result. It is ignored if `+` flag is present.
>   - `#` : alternative form of the conversion is performed. See the table below for exact effects otherwise the behavior is undefined.
>   - `0` : for integer and floating point number conversions, leading zeros are used to pad the field instead of space characters. For integer numbers it is ignored if the precision is explicitly specified. For other conversions using this flag results in undefined behavior. It is ignored if `-` flag is present.
> - (optional) integer value or `*` that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. **In the case when `*` is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type `int`.** If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the `-` flag specified and positive field width. (Note: This is the minimum width: The value is never truncated.)
> - (optional) `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies precision of the conversion. **In the case when `*` is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type `int`**. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor `*` is used, the precision is taken as zero. See the table below for exact effects of precision.
> - (optional) length modifier that specifies the size of the argument
> - conversion format specifier

(emphasis mine).

So you'll need to specify an additional integer argument when using `*` either as a field width, or (after `.`) as a precision.